# Which technique to use for sporadical connections to remote program

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I have a set of standalone program instances working on different remote machines.
I want to write a program for our service team that can connect on demand to a program instance for

- check which configuration the instance runs
- call specific methods on the instance

and I wonder which connecting technique would be best. Named pipes? RPC? something else?

### Details

The program is something like a video player running on different client machines. The videos to show vary from daytime (differnt videos in the night) and also from date (different videos at christmas).
Sometimes our service team needs to check if everything is alright out there, espacially if someone files a ticket. In this case the client should be able to connect to the remote program instance, see which files were used for configuration, and change the date for display calculation.

Comment: I feel like SSH is the way to go. SSH into the remote machine and take a look at the configuration files

Comment: Best for service team to have local admin writes on all machines.  Then you can can use from cmd.exe (or equivalent) >machinename//c$:\ (followed by commands).  The dollar sign is for admin.  I think it can also be setup for regular uses that have account on both local and remote machine.  The Group Policies have to be configured properly.

Comment: RPC, is everything else, there are oodles of way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use central server to collect data.

Setup a central application that your clients will connect to.
Provide each client with an [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and some access token to validate that this UUID really belongs to that machine.

#### It can be a HTTP(-S) server:

- Clients should always "heartbeat" to the central server.
- When you need it - request data from it.

Also regarding remote method execution: you can create list of tasks that your client will receive and execute.

#### It can be a socket/websocket server:

- Clients are always connected to your server.
- They should report their status on a timeout basis.
- You can send commands to clients and they will execute them on the spot.

#### Why centralizing?

Usually client machines are hidden behind routers/firewalls and most of the people have no idea how to do port forwarding.

#### What if you don't want centralizing?

Make every device a server. Set up a web server with some type of API.
Make device list or find your device list automaticly by scanning whole local network for them.

If you need a good WebAPI/RESTful server - use ASP.NET Core.
Or you can use simple [`HttpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener).

Why HTTP?

- It's easy.
- Every language has implementation of HTTP interactions

Comment: Collecting information in a centralized server: yes. But the connection for changing the display date (for checking purposes) should be usable in a plug-in-manner, I am looking for something different than a centralized server system.

Comment: Is it acceptable for stability and resource usage to have a HttpListener wait for days or weeks without someone connecting to it?

Comment: It will open a socket and wait for incoming connection. It's not going to consume resources until new client will connect to it. After it will process request - garbage collector will clean everything up.